# I/O exception while sending request to axis2 server in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When I send a request to axis2 client I get a error

Proxy:

```
<proxy name="SOAP_Body" startOnLoad="true">
  <target>
     <inSequence>

        <switch xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"
                source="//m0:getQuote/m0:request/m0:symbol">
           <case regex="foo">
              <log level="custom">
                 <property name="a" value="s"/>
              </log>
              <send>
                 <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://localhost:9001/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
                 </endpoint>
              </send>
           </case>
           <case regex="bar">
              <log level="custom">
                 <property name="b" value="a"/>
              </log>
              <send>
                 <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://localhost:9002/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
                 </endpoint>
              </send>
           </case>
           <default>
              <property name="symbol"
                        expression="fn:concat('Normal Stock - ', //m0:getQuote/m0:request/m0:symbol)"/>
           </default>
        </switch>
     </inSequence>
     <outSequence>
        <send/>
     </outSequence>
  </target>
```

ELB in 9443 offset 0, ESB in 9444 offset 1

so I have sent a request to http://localhost:8280/services/SOAP_Body of ELB
and I get the following error when I have sent a request thru axis2client in esb

> [java] 15/06/30 15:40:43 INFO httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: I/O exception
>   (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused:
>   connect

When I send through SOAP UI for the above endpoint I get

> Wed Jul 01 10:48:06 IST 2015:ERROR:Exception in request: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8280 refused
>   Wed Jul 01 10:48:06 IST 2015:ERROR:An error occured [Connection to http://localhost:8280 refused], see error log for details
>   Wed Jul 01 10:48:06 IST 2015:INFO:Error getting response for [SimpleStockQuoteServiceSoap11Binding.getQuote:Request 1]; org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8280 refused
>   
>   I have enabled clustering and other configuration as in [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/WSO2+Clustering+and+Deployment+Guide)
>   
> But when I send request to ESB alone without getting through ELB I get the desired output.

When I give AllowAll in axis2.xml in ELB i get the new error in ELB server

> Error - DynamicLoadbalanceEndpoint application member not available

What would be the problem? Please help me out.

Did any of you got sample 57 in wso2 esb for dynamic endpoint working? If yes please help me in configuring. I have configured as in documentation but i couldnt get it working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your question.

1. Post the full stack trace.
2. Where is your axis 2 service being hosted? WSO2AS?
3. What is your axis 2 service endpoint.
4. Post your send mediator xml config.

Comment: added all the info you have asked for, please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the endpoint is working correctly...

Please try this on the web browser:
http://localhost:8280/services/SOAP_Body?wsdl
and see whether or not you get the wsdl of the proxy.

Comment: no, i'm not able to get the proxy's wsdl. then how can I send request to ELB so that it will automatically redirect to manager and worker

Comment: your service is not being hosted on this port. Try 8281 once.

Comment: I have the service hosted in 8281 and 8282 as they are manager and worker. but i want elb to send the request to worker. Can you please help me in this regards. thanks